# Replace Solution arrow in list of list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, functional-style, rule

I have solutions like

```
sol = {{5, {{x -> 7, y -> 3}}}, 
       {7, {{x -> 11, y -> 5}}}, 
       {11, {{x -> 211, y -> 137}}}, 
       {13, {{x -> 11, y -> 3}}}};
```

And I want to get

```
{{5, 7, 3}, {7, 11, 5}, {11, 211, 137}, {13, 11, 3}}
```

How can I do it with `ReplaceAll`?

Comment: `sol /. {a_, {{Rule[_, b_], Rule[_, c_]}}} :> {a, b, c}` is one way to do it, but `Flatten /@ sol /. Rule[_, z_] :> z` is shorter.

Comment: Another possibility (without `ReplaceAll`):  `{#1, #2[[1,1,2]],#2[[1,2,2]]}&@@@sol`

Comment: `Flatten /@ sol /. Rule -> Last` is quite minimal; but see my solution below for a safer solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one must stick to `ReplaceAll`, I agree with the solution by @LouisB in the comment. But there are other solutions, too.

One can use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html), which I would prefer:

```
Cases[#, _?NumericQ, -1] & /@ sol
```

Or [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) with [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) also qualifies:

```
Flatten /@ MapAt[Values, sol, {All, 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to all solutions presented so far, I highly recommend you make use of a replacement in order to ensure the order of the extracted numbers:

```
Flatten@{#[[1]], {x, y} /. #[[2, 1]]} & /@ sol
(*    {{5, 7, 3}, {7, 11, 5}, {11, 211, 137}, {13, 11, 3}}    *)
```

In this way, you can be sure you always get `x` before `y`, even if the list of rules has a different order.